# Pandas Calculate Monthly Churn Rate by Matching to Baseline of Previous Year

Tags: python, pandas

I need to calculate churn rate of each month for millions of users.

Monthly churn rate = number of churned users in the month / total number of users in Dec of previous year

A user is considered churn for the month if the user exist in baseline (Dec 2016) and sales is less than 1 in current month

I have a simple data frame of YearMonth, User and the Sales.

Note in this simple example, there can be new user 'D' in the month but since 'D' is not in Dec of previous year, it is not considered in the baseline for churn rate calculation.

```
YearMonth   User    Sales  Year  Month
201612      A       2      2016  12
201612      B       2      2016  12 
201612      C       2      2016  12
201701      A       3      2017  1
201701      B       0.5    2017  1
201701      C       1      2017  1
201701      D       1      2017  1
201702      A       2      2017  2
201702      B       3      2017  2 
201702      C       2      2017  2
201702      D       0.5    2017  2
```

**What is the most efficient way to calculate churn rate?**

```
YearMonth   User    Sales   Churn or Not?   Churn Rate  In Baseline?
201612      A       2       0               NA          1
201612      B       2       0               NA          1
201612      C       2       0               NA          1
201701      A       3       0               1/3         1
201701      B       0.5     1               1/3         1
201701      C       1       0               1/3         1
201701      D       1       0               1/3         0
201702      A       2       0               0/3         1
201702      B       3       0               0/3         1
201702      C       2       0               0/3         1
201702      D       0.5     0               0/3         0
```

**Required data frame output**

```
YearMonth   Churn Rate
201612      NA
201701      1/3
201702      0
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC

```
s=df.pivot(*['YearMonth','User','Sales'])
s=s.loc[:,s.iloc[0].notna()]
s.lt(1).sum(1).drop(201612).reindex(s.index)/s.shape[1]
YearMonth
201612         NaN
201701    0.333333
201702    0.000000
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Sorry i don't get this! .pivot(*df.columns) also gives error

Comment: `df.pivot(*['YearMonth','User','Sales'])`  is exactly  `df.pivot('YearMonth','User','Sales')`